# Rails: Calculate time using time identifier stored in database as "string"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I would like to calculate future dates like this:

```
Date.today + 1.year
Date.today + 1.month
```

To determine, if the future date needs to be one `month` or one `year` into the future I request the `duration` from a database. The `duration` value is saved as a string.

```
end_date = Date.today + 1.Duration.find(order.duration_id).duration
```

I believe that the above code executes as follows:

```
Date.today + 1."year" #the quotes cause an error
```

How do I remove the quotes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In rails, the way `1.year` works, is `:year` is an instance method on `1`. In ruby, to evaluate an arbitrary method on an object, you just use `send('method_name')` or `send(:method_name)`

If you have your duration as a string, you can use `:send` to evaluate the actual duration:

```
duration = "year"
1.send(duration) == 1.year
```